# Adding the "render" operator to a menu (addon)

Tags: scripting, add-on, operator

I tried to add `bpy.operator.render.render()` to a menu (e.g. invoked via <kbd>Q</kbd> key) for quick access, but the rendering operation executed via the menu runs without having the rendering image shown and without showing the rendering progress and without the ability to cancel (escape) the rendering.

If the same operator is placed within a panel the rendering operation works just as expected.

Is there a solution to having the render operation to work as expected within a pop-up menu?